# I have a second Activity on Click then how can I get the item form the spinner in the main activity then display it in textview in third activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, onclick, spinner

I have a second Activity on Click then how can I get the item from the spinner in the main activity then display it in textview in third activity?

I have three's Activity here,

The main activity which is have a spinner with item one, two and tree

then in the second activity I have button to click and get the item from the spinner

and I have third activity to display the item in the textview but it change to integer 1,2,3

How can I managed that?

Thank you

Comment: What you want to show, the item selected or the entire view ?

Comment: the item selected example when I choose from  the spinner item "one" then I click it in button in second activity I wan it to display in textview as "1" not one.

Comment: You can pass like this any way you are getting 1,2,3 right ?

Comment: Yes,I want to get the value from spinner as one,two and three and change it in int.

Comment: int value = ( selected == "one" ) ? 1 : (selected == "two") ? 2 : 3; or u can set tag for spinner items while creating it as 1,2,3 and on click get the tag value that will also work

Answer (score 0):

Send the Spinner value from Activity_1 to Activity_2 using an Extra.

That way whether the user clicks the button or not in Activity_2, you will have the value.

Send the same value to Activity_3 using an Extra.

Other wise, store the spinner value in a SharedPreference and use it whereever you want